# SQL/Flask display name instead of ID

Tags: javascript, sql, vue.js, flask

I'm trying to display the name of the item instead of the id when im using autocompletion. By now the search is only working using the id. Using MySQL and Flask.

```
@app.route('/items')
def obtenir_items():
    connexion = obtenir_connexion()
    cur = connexion.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM item")
    resultat = cur.fetchall()   # retourne tous les résultats et on doit boucler dessus
    liste = []
    for rangee in resultat:
        liste.append({"id": rangee[0], "nom": rangee[1], "prix": rangee[2], "unite": rangee[3]})
    return json.dumps(liste)


@app.route('/items/<id>')
def obtenir_item(id):
    connexion = obtenir_connexion()
    cur = connexion.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM item where id = %s", (id,))
    resultat = cur.fetchall()   # retourne tous les résultats et on doit boucler dessus
    liste = []
    for rangee in resultat:
        liste.append({"id": rangee[0], "nom": rangee[1],
                  "prix": rangee[2], "unite": rangee[3]})
    return json.dumps(liste)



if __name__ == "__main__":  # lance l’application
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Is your question asking about `displaying name` or `searching by name`? Meanwhile, why not use `SQLAlchemy` since you're using Flask.

Comment: and what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a SQL Query to search by name like an auto-completion: here's what                   I did :
`"SELECT * FROM item where nom like %s", ("{}%".format(nom),))`